# Using crosstab with NULL value columns

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a script that generates an output like this -

```
business  name      month   count
home      SPRINGS   April   3
home      SPRINGS   January 31
```

How do I output this like so -

```
business  name      Jan  Feb Mar April
home      SPRINGS   31           3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the amount of months is finite, I guess you could adjust this script of yours to already deliver the counts in columns:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (business,name)
  business,name,
  count(*) FILTER (WHERE month ='January') AS jan,
  count(*) FILTER (WHERE month ='February') AS feb,
  count(*) FILTER (WHERE month ='March') AS mar,
  count(*) FILTER (WHERE month ='April') AS apr
  .... 
  count(*) FILTER (WHERE month ='December') AS dec
FROM t GROUP BY 1,2;
```

Demo: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=7ba5a23e88287140ea47e7c6899d8cf5)